# I'm using two sql fields from two different tables in sql to populate a select box

Tags: php, html, sql

Here's my sql query:

```
select count(b.code) as count_pt, a.id from event.dbo.dxcode a

left outer join event.dbo.patient_dg() b on a.id = b.diagcode

group by a.id 
order by count_pt desc
```

The second field "id" is the field with the sorted data that I need to populate the select box with.

Is there a way to hide the first field which is being returned as well.

Comment: You've only posted a SQL statement, which doesn't help illustrate how you're populating the select input. Edit your question to include more code.

Comment: please consider to accept an answer (click tick mark on the left) if it actually answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Simply don't select it:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM ...
ORDER BY count(b.code)
```

or just don't use it when you fetch the row in your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

control by your PHP code which data goes into your `select`. Let's assume that all your rows from the db are in the associative array `$rows`:

```
$h = '<select name="myselect" id="myselect">';

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    $h.="<option value=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['somenameorsomething']}</option>";

}

$h.='</select>';

echo $h;
```